# SQL server html table color only on single column using t-sql

Tags: html, css, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on the below script. I have successfully made an HTML table from table. But the requirement is that the column `NEED_TO_BE_Checked` should be the `RED` color but not all of the rows.

I used the condition `case when NEED_TO_BE_CHECKED = 'YES' then '#F78181' end AS [@bgcolor],` to color all rows in the output but the column `Need_to_be_checked` only should be highlighted. Kindly help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code is quite incomplete, without a bit more that represents the TABLE, TR and TD tags, it is hard to answer

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how I have created an HTML table and made individual cells in the table a certain color.

You need to define a class for your TD tag something like this:

```
<head>
<style>
td {
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #666666;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
td.red {
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #666666;
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
</style>
</head>
```

When you build your HTML table, concatenate a special string, such as [class_red], with your data value. In the example I am making even numbered system type ids have a background of red.

```
declare @table varchar(max)
select @table = (
   select td = name
        , td = case when system_type_id % 2 = 0 then '[class_red]' else '' end
             + cast(system_type_id as varchar)
   from   sys.types
 order by name
 for xml raw('tr'), elements
)
```

Once the table has been created, replace the TD tag and [class_red] with the correctly formatted TD tag.

```
set @table = replace(@table, '<td>[class_red]', '<td class = "red">')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: in the else part you can add the default color code which you want to keep for unchecked values.

Comment: Thanks. I added some actual formatting for the plain TD tag.

Comment: i am really Sorry for late reply! it really worked thanks a lot for your help.